# Difference between Tibco businessworks 5.x and 6.x

Tags: tibco, businessworks, tibco-business-works

Sorry to ask this question here (this is not technical) but I am not aware of any other site; let me know if you do.

I am trying to find new things that were added in Tibco Businessworks 6.x. I have referred to following URLs. And although they do talk a lot about Tibco, they do not mention *what is new* in Tibco Businessworks 6.0.

Could you help?

URLs referred:

https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activematrix_businessworks/6.3.0/doc/html/GUID-2898FE5F-AC5D-45FB-A473-81CCE9BFAB4E.html
https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activematrix_businessworks/6.1.0/doc/pdf/TIB_BW_getting_started.pdf
https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activematrix_businessworks/6.1.1/doc/pdf/TIB_BW_samples.pdf
https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activematrix_businessworks/5.10.0_june_2012/doc/pdf/tib_bw_administration/tib_bw_administration.pdf
https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activematrix_businessworks/6.2.0/doc/pdf/TIB_BW_administration.pdf

https://www.tibcommunity.com/tibco-activematrix-businessworks

https://docs.tibco.com/pub/bwsp/6.1.0/doc/html/GUID-C8BA2B53-6A16-4286-8B5C-0DCF9C6C1263.html
http://tibcobwblog.com/2016/02/29/bogusroot-our-new-bw6-friend/#more-916
http://tekslate.com/tibco-business-works-6.x-training

Thanks in advance,
-Neel.

Comment: I believe that you should check the documentation of release of 6.0.0 such as release notes etc.

Answer (score 2):

TIBCO BW 5.x and BW 6.x are different product branches. TIBCO BW 6.x is a successor of tibco bw express which was directed atsmaller companies, while BW5.x was (and still is) directed at enterprises. Basically they're different products with similar names.

As a note, I can point out that last time I've checked official support end dates for both products, BW 5.x had later end dates than BW 6.x. I suppose BW 5.x has a bigger customer base.

Answer (score 0):

With BW 6.x REST palette is standard and not a separate plugin you need to purchase. IDE for development is based on Eclipse and deployment is possible directly from BW studio and plugins are available to integrate with Maven etc.. so basically CI/CD is possible. As IDE is eclipse based Design/Debug/Java etc...perspectives are possible.